# Error - Java Runtime Environment 6 version 1.6.0

Tags: java, runtime, environment

I have installed Java Runtime Environment 6 version 1.6.0 (jre-6-windows-i586.exe) on Windows 7 Pro 64 bits.

When I open the command line and type **java -version**, i'm getting the following error message:

The procedure entry point _wcstoui64 could not be located in the dynamic link library msvcrt.dll

[image]

I click the button OK, then I got the following error message:

The procedure entry point strncpy_s could not be located in the dynamic link library msvcrt.dll

[image]

How to fix these 2 errors messages ?

**Note:**
I'm getting these error messages only on my computer at work.
However, I installed the same version JRE on my desktop at home (Windows 7 Pro 64 bits) and it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `jre-6-windows-i586.exe` is the 32-bits version.

Installing the 64-bits version (`jdk-6-windows-x64.exe`) may solve your problem.

Comment: in my case i need to install 32 bits version because it's a requirement for BlackBerry SDK. Plus, it's working on my personnel computer except the one in the office.

Answer (score 1):

Your original msvcrt.dll was propably replaced by a 3rd party software (new installed software or malware/virus).
You can try to restore msvcrt.dll by either opening a command prompt as administrator and run **sfc /scannow** or by restoring a previous system state.
Other hints can be found [here](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/msvcrt-dll-not-found-missing-error.htm).